# No definite solution on Windows for Cannot find module 'graceful-fs' Error on React Native App Create Start Up

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

```
`PS C:\Users\Adrien\Documents\ReactNativeProjects> npx react-native start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\gracefulifyFs.js
- C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at _gracefulFs (C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\gracefulifyFs.js:15:39)      
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\gracefulifyFs.js:22:1)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Adrien\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\tools\\gracefulifyFs.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Adrien\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\bin.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Everytime I tried to create an App I got this as a response.

I tried to Open a Project like,
npx react-native init App2

I was expecting was for the project to get built, appear so that I could see all the project files.
I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling like,
npm install 'graceful-fs'
I tried the other solutions here too like apt-get or sudo and curl but it didn't work in my terminal`